# A quick way to search for certain lines of code through many files in a project

Tags: linux, search

I am currently working on a C project that contains over 50 .h and .c files. I would like to know if there is a quick way to search for certain lines of code (like ctrl+f for a window for example) without having to actually search each file one by one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried using notepad++ ? What OS are you using?

Comment: This is really going to depend on your code editor or IDE, and your OS.

Comment: `grep` if you're using Unix/Linux, there's windows versions of that too. But this really has nothing to do with C code

Comment: I'm using a Linux OS and using a text editor (gedit) for my code.

Comment: The given close reason is inapplicable - as the close message itself says **"unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"** which is clearly the case of this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Linux/Unix there's a command line tool called [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) you can use it to search multiple files for a string. For examples if I wanted to search for `strcpy` in all files:

```
~/sandbox$ grep -rs "strcpy"*
test.c:    strcpy(OSDMenu.name,"OSD MENU");
```

`-r` gives searches recursivly so you get all the files in all directories (from the current one) searched. `-s` ignores warnings, in case you run into non-readable files.

Now if you wanted to search for something custom, and you can't remember the case there's options like `-i` to allow for case insenstive searches.

```
~/sandbox$ grep -rsi "myint" *
test.c:    int myInt = 5;
test.c:    int MYINT = 10;
```

You can also use regular expressions in case you forgot exactly what you were looking for was called (indeed the name, 'grep' comes from the sed command g/re/p -- global/regular expression/print:

```
~/sandbox$ grep -rsi "my.*" *
test.c:    int myInt = 5;
test.c:    int MYINT = 10;
test.c:    float myfloat = 10.9;
```

Comment: Made a couple of corrections. -I ignores binary files; -i is case-insensitive. The patterns are regular expressions, not wildcard patterns.

Comment: Good points, thanks for the updates @slim

Comment: Thank you - the grep command just saved me hours of manually sifting through files.

Answer (score 6):

install cygwin if you aren't using *nix and use find/grep, e.g.

```
find . -name '*\.[ch]' | xargs grep -n 'myfuncname'
```

In fact, I made this a little script `findinsrc` that can be called with `findinsrc path1, [path2, ...] pattern`. The central line, after checking arguments etc, is

`find "${@:1:$#-1}" -type f \( -iname '*.c' -o -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.hpp' \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -in "${@:$#}"`

- `"${@:1:$#-1}"` are the positional parameters 1 .. n-1, that is, the path(s), supplied as the starting points for `find`. `"${@:$#}"` is the last parameter, the pattern supplied to grep.
- the `-o` "option" to find is a logical OR combining the search criteria; because the "default" combination of options is AND, all the ORs must be parenthesized for correct evaluation. Because parentheses have special meaning to the shell, they must be escaped so that they are passed through to `find` as command line arguments.
- `-print0` instructs `find` to separate its output items not with a newline or space but with a null character which cannot appear in path names; this way, there is a clear distinction between whitespace in a path ("My Pictures" nonsense) and separation *between* paths.
- `-iname` is a case insensitive search, in case files are ending in `.CPP` etc.
- `xargs -0` is there specifically to digest `find -print0` output: xargs will separate arguments read from stdin at null bytes, not at whitespace.
- `grep -in`: `-i`  instructs grep to perform a case insensitive search (which suits my bad memory and is catered exactly to this "find the bloody function no matter the capitalization you know what I mean" use case). The `-n` prints the line number, in addition to the file name, where the match occurred.

I have similar scripts `findinmake`, whre the `find` pattern includes regular Makefiles, CMakeLists.txt and a proprietary file name; and `findinscripts` that looks through bat, cmd and sh files. That seemed easier than introducing options to a generic script.

Answer (score 4):

You can use grep to search through the files using the terminal/command line.

```
grep -R "string_to_search" .
```

-R to be recursive, search in all sub directories too

Then string you want

Then is the location, . for the current directory

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a text editor and the shell, then you can use shell tools like `grep`.

```
grep -R "some pattern" directory
```

However you should consider using an IDE such as Eclipse (it's not just for Java), Netbeans (there is a C plugin) or KDevelop. IDEs have keyboard shortcuts for things like "find everywhere the highlighted function is called".

Or of course there's Emacs...

Comment: This will grep through all binaries as well.

Answer (score 3):

On windows you can use findstr which will find files that contain strings that either exactly match or regular expression match the specified string / pattern.

```
findstr /?
```

from the command line will give you the usage. It can also recurse subdirectories (/s).